# CSS attributes not taking when sourcing in XML file into DIV and iframes

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a situation where I am trying to display log data in XML format.

1. A template for the main page 'mainpage.html' defines the DIV and iframes.
2. A CSS file 'style2.css' defines the attributes of the page and data.
3. A file 'header.html' is sourced into one of the iframes. I'm only doing the last one because I don't want to have to build static headers every time the log file is parsed into table format.
4. And a fourth file, a sample log file, 'import.xml', is sourced into the other iframes. This file reads a log file in XML format and wraps data with `<tr>` and `<td>` tags.

Several problems are giving me grief.

1. My selectors for `<TH>` and `<TD>` tags are not taking effect
2. `<TR>` tags are not working in iframe
3. Vertical scrollbar is not hiding
4. Text is not centering

I don't have this problem if I put everything into one html file.  It's only when I'm sourcing in external files.

I hope I'm being clear enough.  The files that I'm providing are not meant to be production quality. Instead they are only proving out functionality. They are pretty basic and ugly.

Here are the file contents:

**mainpage.html**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css"></link></head>
    <body>
     <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
       <iframe id="hdr-frame" src="header.html"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div id="main">
       <iframe id="main-frame" src="import.xml"></iframe>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**header.html**

```html
    <DOCTYPE! html>
    <head>
     <body>
    <table id="header-table">
    <th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th><th>Header 4</th><th>Header 5</th><th>Header 6</th>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**style2.css**

```css
#container {
  width:800px;
  height:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 21px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#header {
 height: 33px; 
 width:790px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: Red;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
 width:99%;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color:Green;
 color: white;
}

#import-table > tr > td {
 width:30px;
 color:red;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

td {
 width: 30px;
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
}

#hdr-frame {
 width:790px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

#main-frame {
 width:790px;
 height: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

**import.xml**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css"></link>
<body>
<table id="import-table">
<tr><td>Element 1</td><td>Element 2</td><td>Element3</td><td>Element 4</td><td>Element 5</td><td>Element6</td></tr>
<tr><td>Element 7</td><td>Element 8</td><td>Element9</td><td>Element 10</td><td>Element 11</td><td>Element12</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out most of my own problems.  I named the file being sourced is as '.xml', since that was what it started out to be.  But when I added HTML tagging, it didn't matter to the browser that it was now an html file, it still interpreted it as an XML file.